# Custom Membership Provider With Custom Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

How to create membership provider that uses a database of my choice ?

*For example database should have registration tables like these.*

Users(ID, username, PasswordSHA1)

Roles(ID, Name)

Comment: check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx) link, taken from [this](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=custom+membership+provider) website.

Comment: Why are you going to go from the default working secure membership provide to a broken insecure one?

Comment: I have a homework task from academy: Create your own membership provider that uses a database of your choice. Define the tables:
Users(ID, username, PasswordSHA1)
Roles(ID, Name)